# Remove Date and Timestamp from string

Tags: c#, json, string, datetime

I have a string which contains a date and timpestamp which is generated from a `DateTime.Now` looking like this:

```
"2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z"
```

The structure of the string is similair to json array, looking for example like this:

```
  {
    "caption": "Execution time",
    "name": "ExecutionTime",
    "visible": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "path": "executionTime",
    "description": "Execution time",
    "dataType": "DateTime",
    "writable": true,
    "required": true,
    "number: "0000-00000-00000",
    "controlName": "DateTimePicker",
    "defaultValue": "2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z",
    "aspects": []
  },
```

I have it as a string not formated.

How can I remove the DateTime stamp from the rest of the string?

Comment: Is this question about some Homework?

Comment: What is the *desired outcome*, then? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sadly no, the question occured on a task on at my work. I tried to break it down, so it‘s easy to understand.

Comment: i will add some more example

Comment: The string containing only the date is accesible in the future?

Comment: What about deserializing it, changing the value, then reserialize ?

Comment: @Nightscape, your last edit actually made your question *more* difficult to understand.  On your previous edit you said that the date string may appear inside some other string (that happens to look like JSON) and you want to find the date within that string.  But it's unclear if you just want to remove the string (like a string replace with the empty string) or if you want to remove the corresponding property (e.g.: `defaultValue` in your example) by deleting it from the JSON object that the string represents.  Please clarify - especially the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*, [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_)

**Code:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

Regex regex = new Regex(
  @"\""(?<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:\.[0-9]{1,})?Z?\""");

Func<string, string> convert = (source) =>
  regex.Replace(source, m => "\"" + m.Groups["date"].Value + "\"");
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    @"xyz:""2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z"",123abc",
    @"""abc""2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z""xyz""",
    @"xyz : ""2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z"" ,123abc",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-50} => {convert(test)}"));

 Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
xyz:"2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z",123abc           => xyz:"2019-07-18",123abc
"abc"2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z"xyz"              => "abc"2019-07-18"xyz"
xyz : "2019-07-18T11:29:13.623245Z" ,123abc        => xyz : "2019-07-18" ,123abc
```

Comment: [0-9] could be replaced with \d to shorten it a bit

Comment: @Bacon: In .Net `\d` means any *unicode* digit, e.g. Persian one (`۱۲۳۴`). Yes, we can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` and add `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option